# Eu perdi 5 pontos por desfazer meu voto a favor e hoje perdi um ponto por votar contra, não entendi

Tags: suporte

Não entendi esta política de perder 5 pontos por desfazer meu voto a favor, inclusive não há este ocorrido na prática, a pergunta é minha e a resposta que há para ela está com meu voto a favor.

Além disso não entendi também porque perdi um ponto por votar contra uma resposta que claramente não está correta, e ainda justifiquei.

Ocorrências:

- [Como criar automaticamente via Maven arquivos específicos para deploy de cada container?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/67007/8039)
- [Como criar uma classe em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67526/como-criar-uma-classe-em-java/67529#67529)

Comment: Na verdade, um voto *a favor* foi retirado da tua pergunta, sobre o *-1*, independentemente de justificar ou não, é subtraído 1 ponto da tua reputação. Dê uma olhada na página: [O que é reputação? Como faço para ganhar (ou perder) pontos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @qmechanik, o que não entendi é porque perdi os 5 pontos senão removi meu voto. Realmente sobre a perda do outro ponto, não vi que era padrão, obrigado.

Comment: @Delfino, cada upvote que recebe em perguntas, você recebe 5pts. Quando alguém retira o upvote dado anteriormente, você perde os 5pts recebido com o voto.

Comment: @emanuelsn, entendi, então não foi voto negativo.
seria interessante incentivar o pessoal e comentar justificando tanto voto negativo como voto retirado para que possamos melhorar a questão.

Comment: [Vamos fazer uma campanha para incentivar as pessoas a votarem?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2510/vamos-fazer-uma-campanha-para-incentivar-as-pessoas-a-votarem)

Comment: Sorry @Oded, I let this one slip with the wrong tag.

Answer (score 8):

Quando alguém dá um Upvote em sua pergunta, você ganha uma pontuação de +5
Mas, quando alguém retira o Upvote dado anteriormente na sua pergunta, você perde os pontos que foram creditados pelo voto.

- a pergunta recebe votos a favor: **+5**;
- a resposta recebe votos a favor: **+10**;
- a resposta é marcada como “aceita”: **+15** (**+2** para quem aceitou);
- uma edição sugerida é aceita: **+2** (até um total de +1000 por usuário)
- sua pergunta recebe votos contra: **−2**;
- sua resposta recebe votos contra: **−2**;
- você vota contra uma resposta: **−1**

[O que é reputação? Como faço para ganhar (ou perder) pontos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Acredito @emanuelsn que tenha sido alguém que removeu o voto.
Seria interessante haver a perda de ponto quando alguém retira voto de pergunta. Já que o voto somente deve ser dado quando se há a certeza dele.

Comment: Sobre a questão de perder ponto quando retira o voto acho que não é interessante. Já temos um número de votantes pequenos e, se isso fosse implementado, acho que não iria incentivar o voto.

Comment: Mas, caso ainda tenha interesse, abra um novo tópico e exponha essa ideia. Vamos ver o que a comunidade acha. :)